# Could be this condition evaluated to "true" in any case?

Tags: java, unit-testing, refactoring, code-coverage

I have to refactor some legacy code and I've started by doing some tests. This is the method under test:

```
public static synchronized String getWeekFromDate(Date date) {
    String strYyear = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(date);
    String strMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("MM").format(date);
    String strWeek = new SimpleDateFormat("ww").format(date);
    int month = Integer.parseInt(strMonth);
    if (month > 1 && "01".equals(strWeek)) {
        int year = Integer.parseInt(strYyear);
        return (year + 1) + "01";
    }
    return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyww").format(date);
}
```

I have written five test cases and everything is green. Now, I want to refactor it. Condition `if (month > 1 && "01".equals(strWeek))` makes no sense for me. It could be read as:

> Given a date, it's true when the month is not January and the week is
>   the first one in that year

Am I right? Does it make sense? I'm pretty sure I can delete that piece of code without consequences.

My test cases are (all green):

- Given 2018-01-03, it should return "201801"
- Given 2018-02-01, it should return "201805"
- Given 2018-08-15, it should return "201833"

Comment: What language is that? Looks like Java, but I don't see how things like `"yyyy".format(date)` are even supposed to compile. Also, I don't see any reason for that method to be synchronized.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Sorry, I changed some code for the question. Edited!

Comment: Instead of manually choosing a couple of "random" dates you could just write a loop that tests *all* dates in the last 10 years or so. This would have easily found the counterexamples. After that you can just keep the boundary cases counter examples plus some random date in between as tests that should be kept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot safely delete that code. Dates at the end of the year that are in the first week of the new year would qualify for that condition.

Consider the following case, where for December 31st of 2017, you would end up with a result string of `201701`:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").parse("2017/12/31");

String weekYear = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyww").format(date);

System.out.println(weekYear); // "201701" - WRONG
```

There is, however, a far more elegant solution than the code you currently have, relying on [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)'s *week year* (`Y` instead of `y`) pattern:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").parse("2017/12/31");

String weekYear = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYww").format(date);

System.out.println(weekYear); // "201801" - CORRECT
```

In unit testing, you should first and foremost address the boundary cases. Dates like the first and the last day of the year would definitely qualify as boundary cases here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, in your example, I'm not getting "201801", but "201752"

Comment: I think the difference in output might be timezone-related. What do you get for the date `2015/12/31`?

Comment: If I use 2018/12/31, it works fine: it returns 201901. Nice point, thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thanks ;D

Comment: If at all possible, you should consider switching to the Java 8 date/time API.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Java 8. How could I improve it using Java 8?

Comment: Here's an overview: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html